# BigQuery- Update table with Left Join and Cast function (Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CAST)

Tags: string, google-bigquery, casting, left-join, int64

In BigQuery, I'm trying to update a column 'PSB' having all null values in table t1, from another table t2 having column 'SB'. The issue is with the Key data field while doing Left Join. The data type of key in table t1 is String and in table t2 is Integer.
table1 key name: 'PC'
table2 key name: 'art'

I'm using the following code:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET PSB = IFNULL(sb, null)
FROM (
  SELECT cast(a.PC as INT64), b.art, b.sb
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
  on cast(a.PC as INT64) = b.art
) t2
WHERE t1.(cast(a.PC as INT64)) = t2.art
```

I'm getting following error:
"Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CAST"

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly your error(s) & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in the `WHERE` clause is off, and the `CAST` should include the entire expression.  Try this version:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
SET PSB = IFNULL(sb, NULL)
FROM
(
    SELECT b.art, b.sb
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b
        ON CAST(a.PC AS INT64) = b.art
) t2
WHERE CAST(t1.PC AS INT64) = t2.art;
```

In addition, the current `WHERE` clause:

WHERE t1.(cast(a.PC as INT64)) = t2.art

does not make sense, since it should be correlating the two tables involved in the join.  The LHS should be referring to `table1` in the outer query.